# Dynamically created object returns undefined on attempt to access its key value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a student object that looks like this...

```
{
  Freshmen: [{id: 3}, {id: 5}],
  Sophomores: [{id: 2}, {id: 6}],
  Juniors: [{id: 1}, {id: 8}],
  Seniors: [{id: 9}, {id: 4}, {id: 7}]
}
```

I need to do a look up for students based on the ids in the arrays. What I need to be returned is an object that looks exactly the same but where instead of the objects containing just the ids, I now have the full object retrieved from the database.

Inside my angular component.ts file, I am attempting to do so in the following way...

```
  private getStudents(obj) {
    const result = {};
    for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
      obj[key].map(item => {
        this.studentsService.geStudentById(item.id).subscribe(res => {
          result[key] = [];
          result[key].push(res);
        });
      });
    }
    return result;
  }
```

I have a service injected into the component. The service has a method which gets students by the id and I'm calling the service method inside `getStudents()`. The service returns the respective student objects which I am then pushing into the array.

Later I am calling the function and assigning the results to a variable `studentDetails` like so...

```
this.studentDetails = this.getStudents(studentObj);
```

Everything seems to be working fine except that when I try to do... `console.log(this.StudentDetails.Freshmen);` for example, I get `undefined`.

Am I going about this the right way or is there some better way I could handle it, like maybe using `arr.reduce()` instead of `arr.map()`? Although I have tried reduce and it only returns one item for some reason.
Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `.subscribe` occurs asynchronously, but `return result` is synchronous. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: It all depend where you call the `getStudents` and where you `console.log` them. If the console.log is `outside of the (async) getStudents scope` it will return undefined. Is `this.studentsService.geStudentById` an async call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `return` statement is executed before your async `getStudentById()` requests have completed.

I would suggest using [RxJS](https://www.learnrxjs.io/) and then zipping your requests together and do something with the data once you have all the results from the requests.

With RxJS your function could look like this:

```
private getStudents(obj) {
  const result = {};

  // Array to store all the observables
  let observables: Observables<void>[] = [];

  // Generate all the observables with the respective parameters
  for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    obj[key].map(item => {
      observables.push(
        this.studentsService.geStudentById(item.id)
          .map(res => {
            result[key] = [];
            result[key].push(res);
        });
      });
    );
  }

  // Zip them together and wait for all of them to emit a value
  of(...observables)
    .pipe(zipAll())
    .subscribe(() => {
      return result;
    });
}
```

Additionally, it might be better performance wise to fetch all the students at once and then filtering them instead of making multiple requests just for a single student (depends on the number of students thought).

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a asynchronously before return `result`. What is happening is that your function is returning an empty object `{}` before the all requests are completed.

You need something like this (need some refactor):

```
function getStudents(obj) {
const result = {};
const requests=  [];
for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
   obj[key].forEach(item => {
    let currentRequest = this.studentsService.geStudentById(item.id)
    .subscribe(res => {
      result[key] = [];
      result[key].push(res);
    });
    requests.push(currentRequest)
  });
}
return Observable.forkJoin(...requests).subscribe(() => {
    return result;
})
```

}

Then set the `studentDetails` prop like this:

`this.getStudents(studentObj).subscribe(result => this.studentDetails = result)`